# Firebase Database Keep re-inserting nodes when deleting them

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 records in Firebase databases.

I tried to truncate my database, it keeps coming back

[image]

I even tried via **Firebase CLI**

[image]

I still can not get rid of those records on my users table.

How would one go about stopping this?

Comment: Your image is very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: I'll upload the better resolution one. sorry.

Comment: I hope you can it better now. I upload the 800 px one.

Comment: The image is basically trying to show users that I did try to truncate but for some reasons Firebase, kept adding back in. I don't know what cause that and how to prevent that.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Functions?

Comment: I use firebase real-time database. Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: @JenPerson Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any bug in this area right now, and could just delete data myself. Can you check the JavaScript console of your browser for any relevant error messages?

Comment: The likely answer here is that you've been logged out of the admin console and have ended up in some weird state (probably detectable by looking for errors in js console). You may also have client apps rewriting the values on change (you could verify this by altering your security rules to temporarily prevent writes).

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bug, but you can remove the `users` node in the code:

```
let db = firebase.database();                   
let ref = db.ref(); 
ref.child("users").delete();
```

Comment: let me try that. Thanks for help.

Comment: that's using javascript, not sure what language you are using though

Comment: I use swift sorry to add as tags.

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#delete_data just call removeValue() on the path

Comment: I've tried to delete the console ... does seem to go away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185084/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-kyo).